# Move 2000 objects from one S3 bucket to another

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to move around 2000 S3 objects from one S3 bucket to another in the same region and in the same **AWS** account. I have a list of S3 keys which I need to move (Not every object in the bucket). If I'm using a `forEach` loop for each key and use `s3Client.copyObject()` then the request times out after 30 seconds and it is able to copy around 200 objects. What should I do in this situation.

My code looks like this

```
List<String> s3Keys;   // size of list is 1000
s3Keys.forEach(key -> 
    s3Client.copyObject(bucket1, key, bucket2, key)
);
```

It keeps running for 30 sec. and then times out.

Comment: Make certain you aren't running these moves in threads. We can't check code we can't see. And add retry logic. Again, can't help when we can't see the code. You should have included it in the question. Not make us gaze into our crystal balls.

Comment: Have you considered the use of `--recursive` for your list of keys, instead of moving each object using for loop? [AWS CLI S3 mv](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/mv.html)

Comment: Are you running this code inside an AWS Lambda function? If so, **increase the timeout setting** to allow the function to have move time. The copy is done sequentially, so it takes a while.

Comment: Increasing the timeout doesn't seem to be a good approach in my use case.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably try using S3 batch operations.

Comment: This would be a better answer if there was a more specific command, or an example